# Log a raised exception in stdout logger Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

currently i am logging all my test from the console. I mean whatever is being displayed in console is being logged in the log file. However, if there is any exception raised during the script execution it is not being logged though its shows in the console.

Following is my logger class:

```
class Logging(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
       self.files = files

    def write(self, obj):
       for f in self.files:
         f.write(obj)

sys.stdout  = functions.Logging(sys.stdout, logfile)}
```

Thanks,
Tejas

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions get written to `sys.stderr`, so you have to set up a logger for that file handle, too.

You may want to look into using the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module for this sort of thing, though.